# Selenium parallel run-Test cases are getting failed in middle when we run them parallel with Thread Local concept,Throwing diff errors for each run

Tags: multithreading, selenium, parallel-processing

When I do parallel run with Thread Local concept. It is launching browsers and test cases are running parallel but on of sudden they are getting failed and browser is getting closed as it is @AfterMethod event.

It would be great help if someone helped me.

Code:- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4eRENutkuL0eWo0RHZPclgwUWs

---

Error:-

```
un 16, 2017 4:25:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //img[@pc-id = 'logo-big'])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'TNAKKA21D0RG2', ip: '10.96.132.116', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: com.emergya.selenium.drivers.EmergyaChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41), userDataDir=C:\Users\tnakka\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8656_4015}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.104, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: f5fdba75431a5c436e43acbb14e76291
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//img[@pc-id = 'logo-big']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

2. WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //img[@pc-id = 'logo-big'])
   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:19258 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
   System info: host: 'TNAKKA21D0RG2', ip: '10.96.132.116', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
   Driver info: driver.version: EmergyaChromeDriver
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
3. WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //img[@pc-id = 'logo-big'])
   org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 2 milliseconds
4. java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Code is placed in below location :-

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4eRENutkuL0eWo0RHZPclgwUWs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed by following below statement.

You have to make sure that you have absolutely NO global static variables. Everything has to be thread safe (like your browser instances) when parallel run is implemented